# Kohen as Chazzan During Birchas Kohanim

Tags: birchas-kohanim, tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, kohen-priest

Can a kohen serve as chazzan for mussaf on days when there is birchas kohanim? If so, what is the proper procedure for him to follow?

Comment: I'd note that this would apply to shacharit in Sephardic  (and Israeli) minyanim too, and there it applies every single day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm reading *Shulchan Aruch* 128:20, 22, 25, with *Mishna B'rura*, correctly, the rule is as follows. But contact your local, orthodox rabbi for any practical cases.

Is the *shatz* (leader, "*chazan*") the only *kohen*, or are there others?

- If he's the only one, and he has a *sidur*, he should step toward the *duchan* at "*r'tze*", go on the *duchan* for *birkas kohanim*, do *birkas kohanim* facing the congregation, return to his place, and complete the *amida*.
- If there is another *kohen*, then no one should tell the *shatz* to wash his hands or to do *birkas kohanim*. Did anyone?

  - If so, he should do as described above in the "If he's one only one" paragraph.
  - If not, he should not do *birkas kohanim*.

In all cases, someone not a *kohen* should prompt the *kohanim* and say "*kohanim*" (though not "*elokenu*..."); however, if no one present is able to who's not a *kohen* then the *shatz* should prompt the *kohanim* and say the introduction, unless he's doing *birkas kohanim*.

Comment: I seem to recall a preference for a Yisrael (as opposed to a Levi) to be the prompter.

Answer (score 2):

The Sephardic mesora is that the Sha"tz who is a Kohen covers his eyes and stays silent for the duration of the prayer, as he is essentially taking himself out of the room. Then a non-Kohen calls out "Kohanim!" and leads the entire Birkat Kohanim.

I am not sure what happens when the sha"tz is the ONLY Kohen in the room. He probably says the "Barekhenu baBerakha..." as the Ashkenazim do.

Comment: Most Israeli Shuls, even Askhenazi ones, go by this minhag.